# Firebase Emulator throws cloud_firestore/permission-denied error even though all rules are open

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security, firebase-tools

For the sake of testing, my rules are as open as possible:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write, create: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

I make a call from Flutter to the Firebase **Emulator**

```
final bookDoc = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('books').doc(bookId).get()
```

and I get this error:

> FirebaseException ([cloud_firestore/permission-denied] The caller does not have permission to execute the specified operation.)

This happens only on the emulator. Making the same call to the Firebase server works fine.

I tried calling other documents in other collections, and verified that these documents exist.

I had a past attempt to configure **AppCheck**, but I removed it - from pubspec, removed the initialize function, from Android app/build.gradle. Might there be some other left over that I don't know of?

Any other direction I should look into?

Comment: Are you sure your app is using emulators? Can you show us the code where you are initializing emulator?

Comment: Yes, I know that it uses the emulators. When I am making FirebaseFunctions.instance.httpsCallable calls I see the Firestore data changed in the emulator, and the emulator logs show this activity.  Only when I try to change the data directly from the client it throws this error. Here is my emulator initialization:    const localHostString = 'localhost';
    FirebaseFunctions.instance.useFunctionsEmulator(localHostString, 5001);
    FirebaseAuth.instance.useAuthEmulator(localHostString, 9099);

Comment: You can give a try to either of these 1. Try with the different [version of `firestore`](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/3258#issuecomment-814402977) 2. Change `firestore rules` to `allow read, write, create: if request.auth != null;` 3. pass in an `Authorization: Bearer owner` header as discussed [here](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/1363#issuecomment-498364771)

Comment: These suggestions are not relevant, but thanks.

Comment: Are you still getting same error after changing to `allow read, write, create: if request.auth.uid != null;` ?

Comment: Yes. And `true` is as open as it gets.

Comment: I tried on my end and I can able to call emulator without any error. Can you share any tutorial or steps you followed with minimal of your code?

Answer (score 2):

OK, this is embarrassing.

I had these in my emulator initialization:

```
FirebaseFunctions.instance.useFunctionsEmulator('127.0.0.1', 5001);
FirebaseAuth.instance.useAuthEmulator('127.0.0.1', 9099);
```

So I saw functions affecting emulator logs, and rule updates appearing in emulator logs, but I mistakenly deleted:

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance.useFirestoreEmulator('127.0.0.1', 8080);
```

I hope it helps someone else who makes this silly mistake.

Answer (score 0):

```
same error [firestore/permission-denied] The caller does not have permission to execute the specified operation.
```

I already changed firestore.rules in every way

```
{
  "firestore": {
    "rules": "firestore.rules",
    "indexes": "firestore.indexes.json"
  },
  "functions": [
    {
      "source": "functions",
      "codebase": "default",
      "ignore": [
        "node_modules",
        ".git",
        "firebase-debug.log",
        "firebase-debug.*.log"
      ],
      "predeploy": ["npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run lint"]
    }
  ],
  "storage": {
    "rules": "storage.rules"
  },
  "emulators": {
    "functions": {
      "host": "192.168.1.5",
      "port": 5001
    },
    "firestore": {
      "host": "192.168.1.5",
      "port": 8080,
      "rules": "firestore.rules"
    },
    "storage": {
      "port": 9199
    },
    "ui": {
      "enabled": true
    },
    "singleProjectMode": true,
    "auth": {
      "host": "192.168.1.5",
      "port": 9099
    }
  }
}

rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
    match /databases/{database}/documents {

        match /users/{userId} {
            allow read, write: if true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you also getting this only on the emulator? Also - upvote the question to give it more eyeballs and increase the chances of a solution

Answer (score 0):

Also getting this error.
Initializing emulators like this:

```
  const auth = getAuth(app)
  const db = getFirestore(app)
  const functions = getFunctions(app)
  if (useEmulators) {
    connectAuthEmulator(auth, 'http://127.0.0.1:9099', { disableWarnings: 
    true })
    connectFirestoreEmulator(db, '127.0.0.1', 8080)
    connectFunctionsEmulator(functions, '127.0.0.1', 5001)
  }
```

Comment: Is that an answer or a feedback that you had the same issue without actually resolving it?